# Fluentd worker 0 finished with status 0

Tags: fluentd

Running Fluentd 3.5, which seems to give up after failing to flush the buffer. I can see there is a retry_forever parameter which is currently set to false, however I rather find out what is causing it and set a retry threshold to something higher

Config:

```
<source>
    @type tail
    path "XXX"
    tag "XXX"
    pos_file "XXX"
    <parse>
      @type "json"
    </parse>
  </source>
  <match *.**>
    @type forward
    compress gzip
    buffer_type file
    buffer_path d:\dynamo\td-agent\buffer
    flush_interval 10m
    <server>
      host "XXX"
      port XXX
    </server>
    <buffer tag>
      @type file
      path XXX
      flush_interval 10m
    </buffer>
  </match>
```

Logs

```
2019-09-30 13:53:03 +0100 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=0 next_retry_seconds=2019-09-30 13:53:04 +0100 chunk="593c4937d535515d77cffca381c87720" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ForwardOutput::NoNodesAvailable error="no nodes are available"
  2019-09-30 13:53:03 +0100 [warn]: #0 d:/Dynamo/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.7.0/lib/fluent/plugin/out_forward/load_balancer.rb:55:in `select_healthy_node'
  2019-09-30 13:53:03 +0100 [warn]: #0 d:/Dynamo/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.7.0/lib/fluent/plugin/out_forward.rb:321:in `write'
  2019-09-30 13:53:03 +0100 [warn]: #0 d:/Dynamo/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.7.0/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:1122:in `try_flush'
  2019-09-30 13:53:03 +0100 [warn]: #0 d:/Dynamo/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.7.0/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:1428:in `flush_thread_run'
  2019-09-30 13:53:03 +0100 [warn]: #0 d:/Dynamo/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.7.0/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:458:in `block (2 levels) in start'
  2019-09-30 13:53:03 +0100 [warn]: #0 d:/Dynamo/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.7.0/lib/fluent/plugin_helper/thread.rb:78:in `block in thread_create'
2019-09-30 13:53:04 +0100 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=1 next_retry_seconds=2019-09-30 13:53:05 +0100 chunk="593c4937d535515d77cffca381c87720" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ForwardOutput::NoNodesAvailable error="no nodes are available"
  2019-09-30 13:53:04 +0100 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2019-09-30 13:53:05 +0100 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=2 next_retry_seconds=2019-09-30 13:53:07 +0100 chunk="593c4937d535515d77cffca381c87720" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ForwardOutput::NoNodesAvailable error="no nodes are available"
  2019-09-30 13:53:19 +0100 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2019-09-30 13:53:35 +0100 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=6 next_retry_seconds=2019-09-30 13:54:06 +0100 chunk="593c4937d535515d77cffca381c87720" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ForwardOutput::NoNodesAvailable error="no nodes are available"
  2019-09-30 13:53:35 +0100 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2019-09-30 13:54:06 +0100 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=7 next_retry_seconds=2019-09-30 13:55:11 +0100 chunk="593c4937d535515d77cffca381c87720" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ForwardOutput::NoNodesAvailable error="no nodes are available"
  2019-09-30 13:54:06 +0100 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
  2019-09-30 13:57:11 +0100 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2019-09-30 14:00:00 +0100 [info]: #0 detected rotation of d:/Dynamo/logs/dynamo-service-agent-2019-09-30-13.log; waiting 5 seconds
2019-09-30 14:00:24 +0100 [info]: #0 following tail of d:/Dynamo/logs/dynamo-service-agent-2019-09-30-14.log
2019-09-30 14:01:50 +0100 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=10 next_retry_seconds=2019-09-30 14:10:29 +0100 chunk="593c4937d535515d77cffca381c87720" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ForwardOutput::NoNodesAvailable error="no nodes are available"
  2019-09-30 14:01:50 +0100 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2019-09-30 14:10:29 +0100 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=11 next_retry_seconds=2019-09-30 14:29:15 +0100 chunk="593c4937d535515d77cffca381c87720" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ForwardOutput::NoNodesAvailable error="no nodes are available"
  2019-09-30 14:10:29 +0100 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2019-09-30 14:12:22 +0100 [info]: Received graceful stop
2019-09-30 14:12:22 +0100 [info]: Worker 0 finished with status 0
2019-09-30 14:13:24 +0100 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="d:\\dynamo\\td-agent\\etc\\td-agent\\td-agent.conf"
2019-09-30 14:13:24 +0100 [info]: adding forwarding server 'XXX' host="XXX" port=XXX weight=60 plugin_id="object:17760cc"
```

After the above Fluentd stops forwarding logs...what have I missed?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Kubernetes, please check that your memory and CPU reach the limit.

> The pod will get a signal (SIGKILL) when exceeds its memory limit.

**try to increase the CPU or memory to suit your system's needs.**